# How to create thismenu background?

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a design that i should convert to a HTML page, there is a menu with a background and a little space between them, please see the image so you understand what i should do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtkeZ.jpg

What i have (a bit messy):

```css
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, blockquote {
 margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; line-height: 24px;
 background: #eee url(images/body-bg.jpg) center top no-repeat;
}

#container {
 width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; height:1000px; margin-top: -75px; background-color: blue;
}

#destaques {
 margin-top: 75px;
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: grey;
}

#categories {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px; right: 25px;
}

#categories a {
  margin: 0 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

#header {
    overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}

#mllcont {
 height:200px;
 background-color: grey;
}

#slidecont {
 height: 650px;
 background-color: red;
}

#squares {
   width:100%;
   height:250px;
}

#divs div { 
        height: 250px; 
        width: 20%; 
        border: 0px solid red; 
        margin-left: 2.5%; 
        margin-right: 2.5%; 
        float: left; /*Here you can also use display: inline-block instead of float:left*/
        background: orange; 
}

 #header h1 {
  float: left;
 }


#content, #footer, #header  {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Particle</title>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>

 <div id="slidecont">

  <div id="mllcont">

   <div id="logo">
   </div>

   <div id="header">
     <ul id="categories">
      <a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
      <a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
      <a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
      <a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>

   <div id="languages">
   </div>

  </div>


  </div>

 <div id="container">

   <div id="squares">
       <div id="divs">
          <div>One</div>
          <div>Two</div>
          <div>Three</div>
          <div>Four</div>
       </div>
   </div> 

   <div id="destaques">


   </div>
   
   <div id="Projetos">

   </div>

 </div> 

  <div id="footer">
   <ul id="credits">
    <li><a href="http://wordpress.org" class="wordpress">Powered by WordPress</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.blog.spoongraphics.co.uk" class="spoongraphics">Theme by SpoonGraphics</a></li>
   </ul>
   <p id="back-top"><a href="#header">Back to top</a></p>
  </div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: note that you are not opening your LIs, only closing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead

```
<ul id="categories">
    <a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
    <a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
    <a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
    <a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
</ul>
```

use

```
<ul id="categories">
    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
</ul>
```

background menu - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

```css
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, blockquote {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    line-height: 24px;
    background: #eee url(images/body-bg.jpg) center top no-repeat;
}
#container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:1000px;
    margin-top: -75px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#categories {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 0;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1b75b1+0,529282+47,71ac4a+100 */
    background: rgb(27, 117, 177);
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, 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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgb(27, 117, 177) 0%, rgb(82, 146, 130) 47%, rgb(113, 172, 74) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgb(27, 117, 177)), color-stop(47%, rgb(82, 146, 130)), color-stop(100%, rgb(113, 172, 74)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(27, 117, 177) 0%, rgb(82, 146, 130) 47%, rgb(113, 172, 74) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgb(27, 117, 177) 0%, rgb(82, 146, 130) 47%, rgb(113, 172, 74) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgb(27, 117, 177) 0%, rgb(82, 146, 130) 47%, rgb(113, 172, 74) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(27, 117, 177) 0%, rgb(82, 146, 130) 47%, rgb(113, 172, 74) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1b75b1', endColorstr='#71ac4a', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-8 */
}
#categories li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;  
    position: relative;
}
#categories li a {   
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 22px;
    display: block;    
}
#categories li:before{
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}
#categories li:first-child:before{
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="categories">
    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```